# pycryptodome creating error while in stalling pyrebase

Tags: python, pycryptodome, pyrebase

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\91829\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-es9rkk_3\pycryptodome_6f058d74b4754cc2ae3f732917dd2907\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\91829\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-es9rkk_3\pycryptodome_6f058d74b4754cc2ae3f732917dd2907\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\91829\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zlc6kogd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Python310\Include\pycryptodome' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: I also try another method where we first install pycryptodome then pyrebase but that to did not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.